# how to set and get checked or unchecked values in single checkbox using another form

Tags: laravel

i want to set value and retrieved value in the checkbox field when submitting a value from another form hidden filed.

```
<form action="store" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
           <label class="control-label col-lg-3"><b>Enable/Disable App</b> 
           </label>
           <label class="Sg-switch">
               <input type="checkbox" name="is_active" value="<?php $_POST['enable']; ?>"<?php if (isset($setting['is_active'])==1) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>><span class="Sg-slider round"></span>
            </label>
         </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="sg-main-btn sg-primary-tn">Save</button>
```

My submit form is:-

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" name="enable">
  <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="text" name="is_active" value="1" hidden>
          <button type="submit" name="enable" class="sg-main-btn sg-success-btn dis_btn"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" style="display: none;"></i>Yes</button>
           <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sg-main-btn sg-danger-btn" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>No</a>
   </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Good for you, I hope you succeed, did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery.
Give your input id like `id = "input"`.

```
<input type="text" name="is_active" value="1" hidden id = 'input'>
<input type="checkbox" id="input_new" name="is_active" value="<?php $_POST['enable']; ?>"<?php if (isset($setting['is_active'])==1) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>>
<span class="Sg-slider round"></span>

<button id="button1">also add yourclass and type etc</button>

$('#button1').click( function() {
    var active = $('#input').val();
    if(active == 1){
        $('#input_new').attr('checked');
}});
```

Comment: when I submitting value form yes button then form action error showing..

Comment: because here is two buttons. first is for checkbox value set and second for store value in database.

Comment: add new class for button or you can also give id to your button as I gave in input and the $('#buttonid').click....